# jwt.verify not throwing error for expired tokens

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

I'm using JWT - jsonwebtokens in Nodejs.

I'm creating a token and want to throw an error if the token expires. My token is created successfully and I'm checking the token expiry in middleware of Apis in Expressjs.  Then token is sent from Angular in headers and the expiration is checked in middleware.

This is how I'm creating the token:

```
var token = jwt.sign({
                id: id,
                expiresIn: '2m'
            },
                'mysecretkey'
            );
```

This is how my middlware looks like:

```
var token = req.headers['authorization']
var idToken = token.split(' ')[1]
if(token) {
    jwt.verify(idToken, 'myscretkey', (err, decoded) => {
    if(err) {
         return res.status(400).send('Session expired')
    }
    next()    
    })    
}
```

This is what I'm receiving in `decoded`:

```
dec:  {
  id: 'an id',
  expiresIn: '2m',
  iat: 1596744770
}
```

In this case, my token is not expiring even after 2 minutes.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you using [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you added `expiresIn` as part of the payload. But there `expiresIn` has no meaning and you need to use the standard [`exp`claim](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#token-expiration-exp-claim) for expiration:

```js
jwt.sign({
  id: 'an id',
  exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60 * 2),
  iat: Math.floor(Date.now())
}, 'secret')
```

in this example it's 2 minutes.
You can also calculate:
(60 * minutes), (3600 * hours) or (86400 * days) for minutes, hours or days.

`expiresIn` can be used as an option to the sign method as shown in Shivam Soods answer. I think that's the reason for your confusion.

Comment: False. Taken from [here](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#jwtsignpayload-secretorprivatekey-options-callback) --- `expiresIn: expressed in seconds or a string describing a time span zeit/ms.

    Eg: 60, "2 days", "10h", "7d". A numeric value is interpreted as a seconds count. If you use a string be sure you provide the time units (days, hours, etc), otherwise milliseconds unit is used by default ("120" is equal to "120ms").`

Comment: The OP encoded `expiresIn` directly in the the payload. And there it has no meaning. What you're reading and also Shivam Sood wrote in his answer is a parameter to the sign function, that's a difference

Comment: Fair enough.  I must admit I overlooked that.

Comment: @jps is correct, if you are signing your token with expiry time you need to use `exp`, otherwise use `options`

Comment: but I think that's also the misunderstanding of the OP, parameter vs. claim in the payload, easy to get confused!

Comment: True, that's why I added the link to the doc in the answer for OP's reading, hope she gets a better understanding.

Comment: @ShivamSood yes sir - I overlooked that OP had expiresIn as part of the payload and not options. When using options you can use expiresIn, though, right?

Comment: @MattOestreich Yes you can as internally it would convert it to `exp`, so both options are valid but you need to understand what to use where. :)

Comment: This works perfecly for me, thanks! But what I want to have expiry in days, hours, etc.

Comment: @PrachiSharma `+ (60 * minutes)`, or `+ (3600 * hours)` or  `+ (86400 * days)`,

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: @PrachiSharma glad to help

Answer (score 2):

If you want to work with `hours` or `minutes` using `expiresIn` you need to declare it after your `secret` like this

```
let token = jwt.sign(id,'mysecretkey',{ expiresIn: '1h'});
```

Read more about it [here](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#token-expiration-exp-claim)

Comment: This is giving me the error as `Error: invalid expiresIn option for string payload`

Comment: @PrachiSharma wonder what's wrong, it should work, see also the linked documentation.

Comment: @PrachiSharma that is because your payload is a string. You cannot use expiresIn on a string payload. Change your payload to something like `{ foo: "bar" }` and it should work. [See here for more info](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/166#issuecomment-172644934)

Comment: Yes, I've gone through the doc as well

Comment: Okay. I had it working using `var token = jwt.sign({ data: 'an id' }, 'mysecretkey', { expiresIn: '2m' })`