# How to set expiration time using exp in payload with JSON Web Tokens

Tags: node.js, time, jwt

I am using payload to put the expiration time in JWT. I am confused how the time works with this.Here, I saw an example where the expiration time is set to one day.How can i set the time in seconds,minutes or hours?

```
resetToken = user => {
    return JWT.sign({
        iss: 'xyz',
        sub: user._id,
        iat: new Date().getTime(), // current time
        exp: new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1) // current time + 1 day ahead
    }, Keys.JWT_RESET);
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63291238/7329832

Answer (score 0):

```
jwt.sign({
   data: 'foobar'
 }, 'secret', {
   expiresIn: 60 * 60 
});
```

60 * 60 = 1h
Set Number of seconds.

Comment: But, the token is not expiring in this case

Comment: Can you tell me, which npm you are using?

Comment: As in version, i am using 6.14.5 and i am using jsonwebtoken module. I have figured out the way to check for expiry date. I checked expiry date with current date for that But doesn't jwt.verify check for expiry date ?